# Excel VBA DIR only looping once

Tags: vba, excel

I created a VBA that loops through excel files in a stored folder. It loops only through the ones that has the word "BAD" in it's file name. My Problem is DIR seem to only work once? StrFile = "" after the line `StrFile = Dir`. I already tried `StrFile = Dir()` and `StrFile = Dir(StrFile)`

```
    If Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show <> 0 Then
        TheFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)

        Dim StrFile As String
        StrFile = Dir(TheFolder & "\BAD *")
        Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
          'Do Something
          StrFile = Dir 'Check next file.
          'This is where it fails, it doesn't check the 2nd file
        Loop
    Else
        End
    End If
```

**UPDATE:** I noticed something that could be the cause of the problem, and I wasn't that familiar with DIR().

Inside the Do While scrip where it says `'Do Something`is actually a call to another function and that function has a `Example = Dir(ThePath)`. When I try to comment-out or disable the call to that function the script works. So I guess DIR can only be used once? If you use DIR() to loop through files in a folder you can't use another/different DIR()?

Comment: Seems like no other file matched the wildcard. Did you doublecheck that the pattern is correct? It matches only files starting with "BAD "

Comment: Yes that folder has 1 file that is named "Good records.xlsx" and the rest are named "BAD 675.xlsx" or "BAD 2650.xlsx" so on and so fort.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Suggest you double check value of StrFile after `Dir(TheFolder & "\BAD *")` and look closely at the contents of `The Folder`

Comment: Yes the value of StrFile after `Dir(TheFolder & "\BAD *")` is "BAD 675.xlsx" or the first file in that folder.

Comment: Can't replicate with your code.  Open a command prompt, navigate to the directory you're choosing and type `dir "bad "*`.  Are you getting more than one file?

Comment: Yes navigating to that folder typing `dir "bad *"` shows me a list of files that has the word "Bad in them"

Comment: Your edit answered your question.  Dir()'s last search has application wide scope.  If you need to go through the contents of multiple folders, @Trigger's solution is your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This goes through every file in a folder and checks if it's interested (in this case if it's a csv - use `If Lcase(Left(thing.path, 4)) = "bad " then` for your requirements.).

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder("c:\windows")
For Each thing in f.files
    If LCase(Right(thing.path, 3)) = "csv" Then
        msgbox thing.path
        Set doc = GetObject(thing.path)
        msgbox Doc.name
        Doc.close
        Set Doc = Nothing
    End If
Next
```

If you read help it says use the FSO and not the native functions.

> A new feature for Visual Basic is the File System Object (FSO) object model, which provides an object-based tool for working with folders and files. This allows you to use the familiar object.method syntax with a rich set of properties, methods, and events to process folders and files, in addition to using the traditional Visual Basic statements and commands.