# Automatically connect workbooks from specified folder

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula, automation

Let's say that I have a folder (lets call this folder as Data Folder)that contains workbooks with the same format and I have 1 master file that I want all the first sheet (or second) workbooks from the folder to be automatically copied to the master file.

The master file only contains 1 sheet that explains a summary of all first sheet of all the workbooks from Data Folder (the first sheet of master file have different layout with the data project).

Is there any way to make the master file pull all out the first sheet from the Data Folder? So that if I open the master file, all the first sheet from the workbooks inside the Data Folder automatically added to the master file

```
    Sub Merge_Files_First_Sheet_Only()
    'Merges all files in a folder to a main file.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Define variables:
    Dim numberOfFilesChosen, I As Integer
    Dim tempFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
    tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    
    numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show
    
      'Loop through all selected workbooks
    For I = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
        
        'Open each workbook
        Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(I)
        
        Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        
        'Copy only the first sheet of a workbook
        sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        
        'Close the source workbook
        sourceWorkbook.Close
    Next I

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Above is the code I use inside the master file which needs to choose the file that we need to copy but it needs to be done manually (by pressing F8 and choose the workbooks)

It seems that I need to make this code run automatically whenever I open the file and need to add filepath in order to lock it to a specific target (the Data Folder location)

Comment: @braX thanks for the response. I already add the code I use at the moment. Hope this can help you understand my problem

Comment: You can call your procedure from the master workbook's `WORKBOOK_OPEN` event handler. To read files in a folder, you can modify your procedure with code similar to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111655/excel-vba-dir-only-looping-once